# EViews can't import a newly-copied Excel workbook

Tags: excel, windows, eviews

I have an Excel file which I am able to import into EViews. When I copy this file (either manually using the File Explorer or using the shell command in Matlab), I cannot directly read that file into EViews. I get the following error:

```
File 'd:\Temp\15\evxlx\[content_types].xml' does not match expected format in "WFOPEN(WF=...,PAGE=...) FILENAME RANGE=...".
```

But if I open the Excel file after copying it, and save it, I don't get any error and the data import as expected.

What changes in an Excel file when it's copied? And what's changing when it's saved?